# QDomNode.clear() does not remove value of xml tag

Tags: c++, xml, qt

The QDomNode.clear() function should remove the value of the corresponding XML tag. I am using Qt 4.7.

Here the XML

```
<dbLoginData>
    <DB_DRIVER>
        QSQLITE
    </DB_DRIVER>
    <DBPATH>
        /DB/Part.db
    </DBPATH>
</dbLoginData>
```

Now, I want to remove the text value of DBPATH.

```
QFile xmlFile(fileName);
xmlFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

QByteArray xmlData(xmlFile.readAll());
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(xmlData);

QString nodeName = "DBPATH";
QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
//root.firstChildElement(nodeName).setNodeValue("abv");
QDomElement DBPathNode= root.firstChildElement(nodeName);

DBPathNode.clear(); 
xmlFile.resize(0);  
QTextStream stream;
stream.setDevice(&xmlFile);
doc.save(stream, 4);
xmlFile.close();
```

But after saving the file, it does not change anything.

edit:

There is a curiosities, when i use the .clean() function.

This is the object, before I clear the XML tag

[image: QDomElement before using clear()]

And this is the object after using .clear():

[image: After using .clear() at QDomElement]

I don't know why, but the object looses the reference if I use the .clean() function. And that is maybe the reason why I cannot remove the value of the corresponding XML tag

Comment: Shouldn't the value of `nodeName` be `"DBPATH"` and not `"DBPath"`?

Comment: Sry, this is a literal error. In my code, it is correct. I

Comment: Well it becomes a null node after you call `clear`. The docs say about `clear`: *Converts the node into a null node; if it was not a null node before, its type and contents are deleted.*

Comment: What you should do is remove the first child of `DBPathNode`.

Comment: I just thought type and contents, not the name. How can i remove the child? With DBPathNode.removeChild(DBPathNode.firstChild())?

Comment: @thuga: Thank you, it works with removeChild. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the text node by using [`removeChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomnode.html#removeChild):

```
QDomElement dbPathNode = root.firstChildElement(nodeName);
dbPathNode.removeChild(dbPathNode.firstChild());
```